# Creating a reference out of multiple temporaries

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, mingw

I was trying out user-defined literals (introduced in gcc 4.7.1 I believe) and got stuck on how temporaries work.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

class Point
{
public:    
    Point(float x = 0, float y = 0, float z = 0)
    :_x(x), _y(y), _z(z) 
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor\n";    
    }
    ~Point()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor\n";
    }
    Point& operator=(Point p)
    {
        std::cout << "Assignment op\n";
        return *this;
    }

    Point& operator+(const Point& p)
    {
        std::cout << "Returning ref: operator+\n";
       _x += p._x; 
       _y += p._y; 
       _z += p._z; 
       return *this;
    }

    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << "(" << _x << ", " << _y << ", " << _z <<")\n";
    }

protected:
    float _x, _y, _z;
};

Point operator "" _x(const char* l)
{
    float x = atof(l);
    std::cout<<"literal _x\n";
    Point p(x);
    return p;
}

Point operator "" _y(const char* l)
{
    float y = atof(l);
    std::cout<<"literal _y\n";
    Point p(0, y);
    return p;
}

Point operator "" _z(const char* l)
{
    float z = atof(l);
    std::cout<<"literal _z\n";
    Point p(0, 0, z);
    return p;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Point& p = 12_x + 2_x + 3_y + 4_z;
    p.print();
}
```

Upon executing I get the following output:

```
literal _z
Constructor
literal _y
Constructor
literal _x
Constructor
literal _x
Constructor
Returning ref: operator+
Returning ref: operator+
Returning ref: operator+
Destructor
Destructor
Destructor
Destructor
(14, 3, 4)
```

When I change the line to `Point& p = 12_x;` an error is emitted saying that you cannot initialize reference from an rvalue.

When I change it to `const Point& p = 12_x;` I get:

```
literal _x
Constructor
(12, 0, 0)
Destructor
```

I would expect either of these cases instead of the very first one, so my question is: what exactly happens in the first case?

P.S. I'm using MinGW with gcc 4.8.1. Compilation string: `g++ --std=c++11 -Wall main.cpp -o out.exe`

Comment: A reference has no storage in itself (only the address of what it refers to). Therefore, you can't make a reference to an expression (rvalue). To solve this, you will have to produce a variable `Point pp = ...` and then `Point &p = pp;`

Comment: [OT]: you may use `--std=c++11` now.

Comment: you can prevent your `operator+` from being applied to temporaries (so that it won't return *non-const lvalue reference* to temporary) by declaring your operator as `Point& operator+(const Point& p) &` (that is, an extra ampersand at the end)

Comment: @PiotrS. or add `Point& operator+(const Point&&) = delete;`

Comment: @JonathanWakely: but this would disallow: `Point& p = lvalue_of_point + 2_x;`. however, it's debatable if it should work or not, since the main problem here is that `operator+` is implemented in terms of `operator+=`

Comment: Good point - I wasn't thinking straight!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your operator signature for + is not normal, it should return a new temporary not a reference to LHS. You have actually implemented +=.

That is why your plus operator will bind to the non-const reference.

Although you cannot bind a temporary to a non-const reference, you can perform a non-const operation on one. Thus it will compile your + operator when the first term is actually a temporary.

It's the same construct that lets you do `vector<int>().swap( myVec )` to clear the memory from `myVec`, even though `swap()` is a non-const function.

It can also be useful for string-building functions when you want to create them in a one-liner and underneath your object uses `operator<<` on a member `ostringstream`. That turns out safe because the final call you make in such a case is a `str()` call which returns a value not a member reference.

In your case you can also use this construct in your implementation to `operator+`

```
class Point
{
    public:
      Point & operator+=( const Point& ); // as you implemented +

      Point operator+( const Point & rhs ) const
      {
        return Point( *this ) += rhs;
      }
};
```

Comment: while I understand the rest, I have read first sentence for a couple of times already and not sure I understand it completely. Could you elaborate a little more what you mean by "it should replace a new temporary not a reference to LHS"? Are we replacing an object, of which `operator+()` gets called?

Comment: I meant it should return a new temporary, replacing LHS.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `12_x` creates a temporary object, creating a reference to a temporary object will obviously not work, what is referenced when the temporary object is destructed (which it will be once the expression it is in is done)?

However, making a `const` reference will cause the compiler to prolong the lifetime of the temporary object for as long as the reference variable is in scope.

The longer expression with the additions also create temporary objects, but since the `operator+` function is defined to return a reference the result of the whole expression is a reference. Unfortunately, it will be a reference to a temporary object, and using it will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so you're just lucky it works.

---

As noted by Potatoswatter a rvalue-reference should work with the temporary object. This is a new kind of reference introduced in C++11 and is denoted by double ampersands, like

```
Point&& p = 12_x;
```

Comment: I'd +1 except that it's not so "obvious." An rvalue reference would also work.

Answer (score 3):

In this line:

```
Point& p = 12_x + 2_x + 3_y + 4_yz;
```

You get a reference to temporary object which is destroyed immediately after the execution of that line, resulting in undefined behavior. You can actually see that in your log: four constructors are called, then four destructors - so all created objects are destroyed *before you call `print()`*.

When you write:

```
const Point& p = 12_x;
```

it results in prolonged lifetime of a temporary returned by `12_x`, according to `12.2/5 ([class.temporary])`, so the destructor is called only when that reference goes out of scope, that is, this time after you call `print()`.

PS: Excerpt from `12.2/4` and `12.2/5`:

> There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the full-expression. (...) The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. (...)  [ Example:

```
struct S {
    S();
    S(int);
    friend S operator+(const S&, const S&);
    ~S();
};
S obj1;
const S& cr = S(16)+S(23);
S obj2;
```

> (...) The temporary `T3` bound to the reference `cr` is destroyed at the end of `cr`’s lifetime, that is, at the end of the program. (...)

BTW the example here also provides a right way to implement `operator+` (except that you may not even need it to be `friend`). What you wrote in your code should be `operator+=`.